# Can not see blue "g" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, web-applications, eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

After installing all plugins in the world I can not see blue "g" in my eclipse juno so I am not able to run my Web Application.
I have installed:
    -google app tools for android
    -google plugin for eclipse(4.2)
    -google app engine java SDK 1.9,30
    -google web toolkit SDK 
And some update for my eclipse but I got nothing special. Please tell me what I am supposed to do more?

Answer (score 0):

- Just configure Project Facets for your project from Properties by right click on project ans check your facet.
- Or by Configure option on right click just convert to option.

Comment: You know I want to make a new Web Application project but can  not see any web app option in my new project wizard

Comment: You have just follow these steps for making eclipse support for web project: 

 - Click "Help" > "Install new software"
 - In "Work with", paste: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
 - In "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development", check:
 - Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
 - Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
 - Eclipse Web Developer Tools
 - Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

Comment: yes I did! but I have nothing indeed my problem is that I have installed all plugins yet get nothing.

Comment: Usually it happens in this way . 
Could you just paste the snapshot of your installed plugins and eclipse version?